# Regex Split String excluding hyphen

Tags: regex, vb.net, split

I have a Full Name as input and want to split the whole full name word by word but it should:

1. Do not Split the word if contains a Hyphen e.g. `REES-MOGG`
2. Should Split the word if contains an Underscore e.g `REES_MOGG`

---

**HYPHEN**
Example:

```
MRS C REES-MOGG
```

Result:

```
MRS
C
REES-MOGG
```

---

**UNDERSCORE**
Example:

```
MRS C REES_MOGG
```

Result :

```
MRS
C
REES
MOGG
```

---

I am currently using the code below but in vain:

```
Dim str As String() = Regex.Split(names, "\s+")
```

Comment: And what language/lib are you using ? And why no underscore in you regular expression if you want to split on underscores ?

Comment: Simple replace `_` to ` ` doesn't do the job ?

Comment: I have to do check the live data, hence cannot replace anything.This is kind of a filter for acceptance

Answer (score 1):

Just split on `"\s+|_"`, that will split on whitespace, and also on underscores. Your code would be:

```
Dim str As String() = **Regex.Split(names, "\s+|_")**
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/jH5sK5).

For it to split on ampersands too, just add `|\&` to the string:

```
Dim str As String() = **Regex.Split(names, "\s+|_|\&")**
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/yO3aV9).

Comment: Also If i want to Ampersand '&' too while splitting ?

Comment: @user3636465 I've added extra info to the answer to also split on ampersands. If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted via the checkmark to the left of my answer.

Comment: @user3636465 could you please mark my answer as the accepted answer, via the checkmark to the left of my answer? That'll make clear to others searching the internet for this same problem who end up on this page, that this answer was what solved the problem for you.

Comment: Remember that `_|\&` is just `[_&]` (and `&` isn't a regex special character, no need for escape)

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
Dim str As String() = Regex.Split(names, "[\s_]+")
```

Comment: Remember that `(\s|_)` is just `[\s_]`

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim str As String() = names.Split({" ", "_", "&", vbTab}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make your script split on white-space and underscores you simply need to add a character group `[ ]` around the white-space character `\s` in your regex and then add any other symbols which you want to spit on into that group.

```
Dim str As String() = Regex.Split(names, "[\s_]+")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about VB .NET, but you should change your RegEx for sure.

here is an example, though I tested on Javascript.

```
Dim matchForHyphen As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches("MRS C REES-MOGG","[\w]*[^_]*")
Dim matchForUnderscore As MatchCollection = Regex.Match("MRS C REES_MOGG","[\w]*[^_]*")
```

Then you should cycle through the Match objects to get the results.
 eg. matchForHyphen[i] in a For cycle. or a For Each statement

Hope it helps